# Usando ksoap (Android) para consumir WS php (nusoap)

Tags: android

bom dia!

Estou com um pequeno problema:

A biblioteca ksoap está me retornando um erro ao tentar integrar com um webservice nusoap, sempre estou recebendo o retorno nulo, erro:

> 06-07 08:53:23.843 3039-3077/com.example.bomprato.bp E/ContentValues:
>   Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Não sei se tem a ver com os parametros namespace, soap_action e method_name, que podem estar configurados incorretamente. Segue abaixo a minha configuração do ksoap com esses dados:

```
   @Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    System.out.println("INICIO##########################");
    String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:BomPrato#listaIntro";
    String METHOD_NAME = "Notificacoes.listaIntro";
    String NAMESPACE = "urn:BomPrato";
    String URL = "http://www.artistadaweb.com.br/ws/index.php";
    SoapObject resposta = null;
    InputStream resultado;
    try {

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = false;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);



        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.debug = true;

        System.out.println("aqui3");
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        System.out.println("aqui2");
        resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXaqui1");
       // resposta.getProperty("item");


        System.out.println("RESPOSTAAAAA: "+resposta.getProperty(0).toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "fdsdsfds";
}
```

Segue o WS de testes que estou utilizando (apenas o metodo listaIntro que está operando por enquanto): http://www.artistadaweb.com.br/ws/index.php

Conto com a ajuda de vcs, valeu!